# How to read inner data in XML file using Deserializer?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <name>test</name>
 <one>1</one>
 <two>2</two>
</test>
```

And this is my code:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Class main

Sub Main()
    Dim p As New test()

    Dim x As New XmlSerializer(p.GetType)

    Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader("XML.xml")
    Dim p2 As New class1()
    p2 = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
    objStreamReader.Close()

    MsgBox(p2.name)
    MsgBox(p2.one)
    MsgBox(p2.two)

End Sub

End Class
```

And my classes:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class test

Private newname As String
Private newone As Integer
Private newtwo As Integer

Public Property name() As String
    Get
        name = newname
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        newname= value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property one() As Integer
    Get
        one = newone
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        newone = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property two() As Integer
    Get
        two = newtwo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        newtwo = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

It works, it gives me the Message Boxes with the data in the XML file, I'm having trouble however, if I add inner nodes to the XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <name>test</name>
 <numbers>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
 </numbers>
</test>
```

How am I supposed to work numbers out? I know it's a property of test, but it's also a class because it has one and two as properties, so what would the right approach be?

**Update:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <name>test</name>
 <numbers>
  <one>1</one>
  <two>2</two>
 </numbers>
 <numbers>
  <one>3</one>
  <two>4</two>
 </numbers>
</test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deserialize that example XML, you'd want your data classes to look like this:

```
Public Class test
    Private newname As String
    Private newnumbers As List(Of Numbers)

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return newname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            newname = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <XmlElement()> _
    Public Property numbers() As List(Of Numbers)
        Get
            Return newnumbers
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Numbers))
            newnumbers = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Numbers
    Private newone As Integer
    Private newtwo As Integer

    Public Property one() As Integer
        Get
            Return newone
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            newone = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property two() As Integer
        Get
            Return newtwo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            newtwo = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Then you could deserialize it like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim p As New test()
    Dim x As New XmlSerializer(p.GetType)
    Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader("XML.xml")
    Dim p2 As New test()
    p2 = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
    objStreamReader.Close()
    MsgBox(p2.name)
    For Each i As Numbers In p2.numbers
        MsgBox(i.one)
        MsgBox(i.two)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: And would I call the property of the class test? Or just the properties of the class numbers?

Comment: It gives me this error: There is an error in XML document(0,0), when I call the Deserialize method to assign it to the other class: o2 = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader), could it be because it's already deserialized?

Comment: @user1676874 You'd just deserialize it to a single `test` object and access the numbers property through that object.  I updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: It gives me an error on: MsgBox(p2.numbers.one)
Error: 'one' is not a member of 'Integer'.

Comment: You must have copied something wrong.  I tested it here and it works fine for me.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I used your code exactly as it was instead of applying it to mine and it indeed worked. Thanks, by the way, would this code work if I need to deserialize multiple XML files?

Comment: Yes, you can deserialize each XML file into a separate instance of the `test` class.

Comment: Sorry another thing, what would happen if the node numbers was found twice on the XML file? I updated my code to show an example, I already tried calling it again but it gives the same data, 1 and 2.

Comment: Seems to be working! Thanks, just wish I could give you more points for it.